# searchbar not working using js script in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

i used a datatable in my webpage ...but the search bar on it is not working ...

i am using this function to do search ...by putting this in header.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var table = $('#example').DataTable();
           
          $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
              var data = table.row( this ).data();
              alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
          } );
      } );
      </script>
```

i also tried to put out of header.. and used the javascript files also.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2011-04-25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Garrett Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
              <td>2011-07-25</td>
              <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Ashton Cox</td>
              <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>66</td>
              <td>2009-01-12</td>
              <td>$86,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
              <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>22</td>
              <td>2012-03-29</td>
              <td>$433,060</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Airi Satou</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008-11-28</td>
              <td>$162,700</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
              <td>Integration Specialist</td>
              <td>New York</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2012-12-02</td>
              <td>$372,000</td>
          </tr>          
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>
```

I can't understand what the problem is, the snippet works.

The search bar works, help me understand your problem.